# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error for HTTPS subdomain despite wildcard subdomain certificate configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am experiencing an `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error when accessing an HTTPS subdomain `https://portainer.app/` (but in general any subdomain), even though the certificate has been configured for `app` and `*.app` SAN.

**TLDR**: I created new Debian server for docker with hostname **app** and IP **10.1.1.51**. Every computer in domain see both hostname and ip without problems (checked with ping and nslookup). In [XCA](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/) I created *Root CA*, *Intermediate CA* and *Servers* endpoint certificate signed with *Intermediate CA*. *Root* and *Intermediate* Public Keys are deployed on all devices in network. Servers Certificate detail showing many SANs, including:

```
...
DNS Name=terminal
DNS Name=*.terminal
DNS Name=app
DNS Name=*.app
DNS Name=localhost
IP Address=127.0.0.1
IP Address=10.1.1.50
IP Address=10.1.1.51
...
```

On *app* I created 2 docker-compose.yml for *nginx* and *portainer*. Portainer docker-compose:

```yaml
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9810:9443
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./ssl:/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock.
    command:
      - --ssl
      - --sslcert
      - /certs/Servers-Public.crt
      - --sslkey
      - /certs/Servers-Private.pem
```

Portainer is configured for nginx in **portainer.conf** like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name portainer.app;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/Servers-Public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/Servers-Private.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://10.1.1.51:9810/;
    }
}
```

Primary app site is configured in **default.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name app localhost 10.1.1.51;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/Servers-Public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/Servers-Private.pem;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /portainer/ {
        proxy_pass https://10.1.1.51:9810/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /portainer;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

There is **http to https redirect** in booth files (with correct server_name):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name portainer.app;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

After browse `https://app/` Chrome shows correct webpage and that certificate is valid and everything is ok. Also, even if I browse app/portainer or 10.1.1.51/portainer everything works on ssl and secure.

However, as soon as I enter any subdomain (https://portainer.app or random.app) I get an error ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. The same certificate which is valid for app is now invalid for any *.app.

[image: Certificate detail in Chrome]

**I have already done this**: I have checked the *Nginx configuration*, *docker-compose* files, *DNS* settings, and everything appears to be correct. I tried to make an *certificate* again for all original domains, but also a simpler certificate only for 2 CN: *portainer.app* and **.portainer.app*... It **always behaves the same way**.
DNS correctly resolves to the server's IP address 10.1.1.51, and after open site in browser there are no log entry in the Nginx docker logs. I use ESET antivirus, but when I try it directly on a server where ESET is not installed, the result is the same there as well. Any idea where the error is?

Comment: I think that wildcard certificates for second-level domains (like `*.app`) are implicitly rejected by most browsers (see e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/can-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-be-issued-for-a-second-level-domain)...but I'm not sure, hence this comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wildcard certificate should not be issued if it covers domains under different administrative control (i.e. different owners). Otherwise it would be possible that one owner could use its own certificate to impersonate domains which belong to somebody else.

This means it is not possible to have a wildcard for `*`, not for `*.com` but also not for `*.co.uk` (which basically is the UK form of `*.com`). The same as true for `*.app` or `*.dev`.

In general - there is no wildcard for any **public** top-level domain. For everything at a lower level consult the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/).

These rules are enforced in the browser when validating a certificate. This means browsers don't only rely on certificate authorities to not issue such certificates, they also make sure that they don't work even if issued. Certificate validation outside of browser is often not that strict.

See also [Can a wildcard SSL certificate be issued for a second level domain?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/can-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-be-issued-for-a-second-level-domain).

Comment: Thanks, yes, it seems so. Tested on a new certificate just for portainer.app and nothing else - it works. So this question has no solution, only clarification. Personally, I don't see any benefit from this approach except that it works as a 2nd level of protection against mistakes. But I don't believe that any official registrar would allow himself to do *.com. While internally within a company or household it may not matter.

Comment: @Atiris: In general it is a bad idea to use public TLD for internal use from start. If you would have used [domains reserved for internal use](https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-domain-suffix-for-private-network) you probably would not run into this problem. You can also run into other problems with using public domains internally, like not being able to use .dev with plain HTTP since there is a preloaded HSTS for this domain. Similar you should also not use public IP addresses which don't belong to you internally.

Comment: Yes, I understand those reasons, however I am currently at a business with an aaa.com domain and we are preparing to move to a bbb.com domain. I thought it was a good idea to create domain neutral nameservers instead of porting dozens of services from xyz.aaa.com to xyz.bbb.com in a few years. In the end, it might be easier, I don't know now.

Comment: I am thinking about changing names to a TLD server (now is free). So for example *.app.server, *.terminal.server, *.file.server... The question is when someone will come up with the fact that the server will become a TLD :( Is this also a bad idea?

Comment: That's why I recommend to use TLD which are **officially reserved** so that they cannot be used as public TLD - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Reserved_domains